# Gridview daily updating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I currently have a Gridview in ASP.NET VB where you can select a row and the data will then be transported to the next page for entry purposes. My question is there an easy way where I can highlight the row after someone has entered information on this row and for the same day. So if someone enters data for a person today, then tomorrow the highlighting will go away the next calendar day. I appreciate any help.

This is what i currently have.

```
    Public Sub Get_GV()
    ' Fills Gridview with data selected from dropdown-area

    DSADT.SelectParameters("Area").DefaultValue = DDArea.SelectedValue
    Dim dv As DataView = DSconnect.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    GridView1.DataSource = dv
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

    ' Allows you to "select"/Highlight a row without a select button
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.backgroundColor = '#87CEFF';"
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';"
        e.Row.Attributes("OnClick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    'Submits data to next page
    Response.Redirect("RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text & "&Name=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text & "&Rounder=" & DDRounder.SelectedValue & "&Area=" & DDArea.SelectedValue)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Private Sub FormatMyGridView _
               (ByVal sender As Object, _
                ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) _
           Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

      Dim drItems As DataRow

         If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

         drRequest =DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row

         ' get your field from DataItem
         ' format the row based on field value:
         if drItems.YourFieldDateTime.Date = DateTime.Date

           ' hilight the row

           e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

       End If    

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the last modified date in the data returned from your query to bind the grid view and then you can handle the `RowDataBound` event to check the last modified date for each row against today's date, like this:

Code-behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Only check the last modified date for data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' Get the last modified date for each row, possibly in a hidden field control and compare it to today's date

    End If
End Sub
```

Markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
  </asp:gridview>

onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound"
```